# Laravel Error on inserting with foreach: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, oop

What is wrong with my foreach loop.

Its giving me ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

The code below saves Payer successfully but gives me above error on getting to the foreach.

How can i fix this?

```
public function store(CreatePayerRequest $request)
    { 
       
   
        $input = $request->all();
        $payer = $this->payerRepository->create($input);
        {   
            $spouses = Spouse::find('id');
            foreach($spouses as $spouse){
                $spouses = new Spouse();
                $spouses->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $spouses->payer_id = 1;
                $spouses->spouse_occupation='NA';
                $spouses->spouse_name = $input['spouse_name'];
                $spouses->spouse_dob = $input['spouse_dob'];
                $spouses->spouse_emplbiz_add = $input['spouse_emplbiz_add'];
                $spouses->spose_income = $input['spose_income'];
                $spouses->save();
            }
```

Comment: i deleted my answer as i noticed something else you are overwriting the variable `$spouses` inside your loop `$spouses = new Spouse();` but that's what you're looping over.  So you immediately change the data type.  I think you need to do a dump of `Spouse::find('id')` and check that it is an iterable object, and the change the name of the variables inside your loop.  All in all, i'd say it's not really clear what you're trying to do with this code

Comment: it also looks like there is a typo here ` $input['spose_income'];`

Comment: `$spouses = Spouse::find('id');` returns one record only...

Comment: @Makdous `Spouse::find('id');` will probably return `null`, `'id'` is a string

Answer (score 0):

You provided invalid Argument to `Spouse::find('id')`. `'id'` will be considered as `string`. It must've returned `null` which is the cause of the error.

You should try something like: `Spouse::find($id)` because Laravel also expects the `id` to be an `integer`.

`find()` acts upon the Primary Key if you want to set your primary key in your model to something other than `id` by doing

```
protected  $primaryKey = 'slug';
```

And set the incrementing property on your model to false:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: But I have tried : Spouse::find($id) and it gives  me ErrorException
Undefined variable: id. What else should i do.

Comment: Yes, that's because it should be an integer value. For example Spouse::find(1) will fetch the row with id 1 from spouse table. What is your purpose of using foreach loop?.

Comment: My purpose is that a payer can have many spouses and in my create payer form under marital status  I have created an optional livewire form for spouses details if they are married to one or many spouses. If I remove the foreach, and add like 3 spouses details only one of the 3 is saved so I was thinking foreach could do the fix. I appreciate your answers so far and hope this explanation will make is easy to understand and help me fix this.

Comment: Well. If the spouses belongs to a payer. I'm assuming that your payer object contains the attribute ID. You need to give Payer ID as Spouse::find($payer->id). It will return you one record and your loop will be executed only once. You need to change the logic that controls loop if you are trying to add multiple spouses that belongs to one particular payer.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the $payer->id and its no more giving Undefined Variable but its still giving  error of Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at the point: foreach($spouses as $spouse. But if i remove the foreach it works and inserts only one record.  Yes i want t insert multiple spouse for a Payer.And i also want an if statement that will only run when there is a spouse to save. Can you fix my code logic to do that? Thanks in advance.